# A method of attaching event listener, supported by all major web browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I need to write a piece of code that will attach a listener to selected event, and that will work in any popular browser, in any version of it. After doing some searching I came out with following function:

```
function addListener(event, thefunction)
{
    if(window.addEventListener)
    {
        //All browsers, except IE before version 9.
        window.addEventListener(event, thefunction, false);
    } 
    else if(window.attachEvent)
    {
        //IE before version 9.
        window.attachEvent(event, thefunction);
    }
}
```

Quite simple and seems to be self-explanatory.

There might be some problem with `DOMContentLoaded` event, as none version of IE (AFAIK) does recognizes it, and developers are obligated to use `onreadystatechange` instead. Solving this problem also seems to be fairly simple, until Internet Explorer 9. You had to write only an extra line in `else if(window.attachEvent)`:

```
event = (event == 'DOMContentLoaded') ? 'onreadystatechange' : "on" + event;
```

This part was always fired in any version of Internet Explorer and this line provided a simple translation of event name, so a correct one was always used.

But what about Internet Explorer 9 (and above)? In which Microsoft decided that it will drop `attachEvent` in favor of `addEventListener`. But doesn't changed `onreadystatechange` into `DOMContentLoaded`.

I can't use above line in `window.addEventListener` part, because this will rewrite `DOMContentLoaded` into `onreadystatechange` event even for other browsers and fail there, as they use `DOMContentLoaded`.

So, does the only way to solve this problem, is to add browser detection (type and version) to `window.addEventListener` part and if it detects that script is dealing with IE 9 or above, it will rewrite event name from `DOMContentLoaded` to `onreadystatechange` (and supplement other events name with `on`, required for IE), and in case of other browsers, will leave event name not changed?

Or maybe I'm wrong, because as I just tested, neither `DOMContentLoaded` nor `onreadystatechange` is being fired in my IE 8 (first one fires correctly in Firefox / Chrome).

And what about jQuery's `.on()` function (or similar)? Does anyone knows, if it supports cross-browser attaching of `DOMContentLoaded`, so I can be sure that this specific kind of event will be catch by my script, no matter, in which browser or it's version I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) is natively supported in IE9 and above and can be attached through the W3C-standard [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) method which was also implemented in IE9:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log('DOM ready');
}, false);
```

That will work in all modern browsers and IE from version 9 and up.

jQuery 1.x is compatible with IE6+ and any other update-to-date browser. jQuery can hook a DOM ready event cross-browser by shimming support for IE6-8 through the [DOM ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(function() {
    //DOM has loaded, put your code here
});
```

---

`.on()` provides [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), but that's rather unrelated to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. As I wrote in the end of my question, I was wondering, why `onreadystatechange` doesn't works correctly in my IE 8. But since using jQuery solved this problem and works fine in all tested browsers, I've chosen this way and stopped wondering! :]

Comment: IE<9 has many compatibility issues, I'll check it in IE8. Do you mean that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5959237/1331430)'s code doesn't work in IE8?

Comment: Just tested `onreadystatechange` with `attachEvent` on IE8, it seems to fire at least once in my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnSXM/), but it will fire twice when the page is first loaded (I'll test it locally). Thankfully jQuery takes good care of that, trying to understand IE bugs can consume one's sanity very easily. `:)`

Comment: 100% true and 100% agree: Before jQuery, coding so, page would look SIMILAR in IE as it looks in normal browsers was a real nightmare! :]

Comment: Yup, also, I couldn't find an answer as to why `onreadystatechange` fires twice in IE8 (besides it being a cross-browser inconsistency), but I took a look at the [jQuery 1.7.2 source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js) - there are more than a few hacks to assure that IE has the DOM ready and the function only fires once, the main of them being the [scroll hack](http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/) (called at line 484), together with some extra checks. Thankfully there's jQuery to save us a lot of these headaches. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: FYI, not that you care anymore since you are using jQuery, but the simple answer as to why `onreadystatechange` fires twice (or more) is easily answered by the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534359(v=vs.85).aspx - There we see that there are MULTIPLE possible states during the load process, including `loading` and `loaded` - so it fires at each step in that process. The correct usage in a callback is to check for the state you care about. This allows coders to take action at various steps in the loading process.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve oh the good ol' 2 years old answers.. I've figured out how the `onreadystatechange` event works since then -- the name is pretty intuitive, and IIRC I was just lazy to write up a detailed explanation as the problem was already solved, but thanks for putting up the time to write a detailed explanation! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

IE9 supports DOMContentLoaded. See [here](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/DOMContentLoaded/Default.html).

With this in mind, you can pretty much* work on the assumption that, if `addEventListener` is supported, so is DOMContentLoaded.

(* unless someone lands on your page using Opera 8 or Safari 3.0, probably unlikely).

As for jQuery, it defers to DOMContentLoaded where this is supported but otherwise falls back to its historic means of detecting DOM-ready, which involves repeatedly checking the DOM tree to see if `document.body` exists yet. So you can just use its DOM-ready handler:

```
$(function() {
```

without having to use `on()`.

More info on how jQuery does it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959194/how-does-jquerys-document-ready-function-work).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Because I need to bind a function to "DOM ready" event inside another function, I preferred `(document).bind('ready', function() {})` version, which also works fine. Thank you!