# JavaScript/jQuery eventListener - declaring outside of window.onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

How does jQuery achieve declaring an event listener inside of a self invoking function without being in `window.onload`, whereas JavaScript returns null.

```
(function() {
  // returns null
  document.querySelector('#backtotop').addEventListener(self.scrollTop, false);

  window.onload = function() {
    // attaches event correctly
    document.querySelector('#backtotop').addEventListener(self.scrollTop, false);
  };
})();
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't do it in a self invoking function. Are you confusing that with the `$(function() {...})` syntax? That's a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {...})`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does jQuery's "document ready" function work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959194/how-does-jquerys-document-ready-function-work) It simply binds a handler to run when the body has loaded using whatever method is available in the current browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is called event delegation. The idea is to bind event to one of the parent nodes and benefit from event bubling. For example you cam bind event to the body tag:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'backtotop') {
        self.scrollTop();
    }
}, false);
```

You will need to filter necessary target inside of event handler.

In this case it's not necessary for `#backtotop` to be available in DOM by the time of event initialization.

Comment: He's really not asking about delegation. The question shows that the `window.onload` handler successfully binds. There's no delegation done there. But it's worth knowing about in any case.

Comment: I think that OP is actually asking about how is it possible to bind event when the node is not available yet (`// returns null`) without using `window.onload` (when the DOM is already rendered and `// attaches event correctly`).

Comment: Right, but the node in the question is available when the DOM is ready. It's not being added dynamically later. jQuery doesn't use `window.onload` and he appeared to conflate the IIFE syntax with the shorthand `.ready()` syntax. Anyway, like I said, delegation is worth knowing, though to be anything like jQuery's you'd need to test all ancestor elements from `event.target` until `document` to see if a match is found.

Comment: Well in question the DOM is *not* ready. You can clearly see that outside `window.onload` `document.querySelector('#backtotop')` is null, and inside "attaches event correctly".

Comment: And that's my point. When the DOM is not ready, it fails, but when it is ready, it succeeds. jQuery doesn't need or use event delegation to accomplish the same. It binds a handler that runs when the `document` is ready, which is after the script loaded, but before the `window.onload` happens.

Comment: You are probably right, OP confused IIEF with `$(function() {})`.