# how come javascript doesn't crash when referred variable from other file hasn't been loaded yet

Tags: javascript

I have this very simple html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/model/dinnerModel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/view/exampleView.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the javascript files that are included in the bottom are:

app.js:

```
$(function() {
    var model = new DinnerModel();

    var exampleView = new ExampleView($("#exampleView"));

});
```

dinnermodel.js:

```
var DinnerModel = function(){
    // some js stuff
}
```

exampleView.js:

```
var ExampleView = function () {
     // more js stuff
}
```

This runs fine for me, and my question is: why? When app.js is included in its script tag, dinnermodel.js and exampleView.js have clearly not been loaded yet, so I should get an error in app.js saying that DinnerModel is not declared, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does jQuery's "document ready" function work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959194/how-does-jquerys-document-ready-function-work)

Comment: What did you think `$(function () { ..` does?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That doesn't answer this. That question is about how `document.ready` works internally, but not the implications on other scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$(function() {})` waits until dom is ready and that means the other scripts have loaded before the code inside it gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Great question.

It works because you're waiting for the document to be ready, please refer to this website. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Doing `$( document ).ready(function() {` or `$(function() {` is the exact same thing.

By the time the page executes the function inside `$()` the whole content was loaded and ready to use.